# Setting items in android listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am displaying list of students names in a listview. For each student I need to capture signature and create a certificate. So for that I kept two images to parent right for each listitem.
And I kept separate onclick actions for each image. Can I keep in any other way for capture sig and creating certificate instead of two images for each listitem?

Comment: What u mean with: "So for that I kept two images to parent right for each listitem."

Comment: @DanielMartinus He probably meant that two images are aligned to the right side of each list item. But I don't know what exactly did he mean by capturing signature and creating a certificate.

Comment: I mean when capture signature image is clicked that page will open and when certificate image is clicked
certificate page will open. But my question is for each listitem I kept those images. The screen is
not looking good like that. So can we keep in any other way?

Comment: you can use expandable listview also, when you click on the name of student a list expand and show the images